# Possible to animate a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to make a basic space invaders game, using html, css and js. I'm very new to coding, and I'm a bit stuck. I'm having some trouble getting the enemies to go down when they hit the side.

```js
function drawFiende() {
  document.getElementById('fiende').innerHTML = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < fiende.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('fiende').innerHTML += `<div class='enemy' style='left:${fiende[i].left}px; top:${fiende[i].top}px'></div>`;
  }
}
```

```css
@keyframes bevegelse {
  0% {
    left: -230px;
    top: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 250px;
    top: 0%;
  }
  51% {
    left: 250px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -230px;
    top: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="fiende"></div>
```

Right now I'm using *CSS* to move it from side to side, it's a bit meh. But I can't make it go down. Since It will only go down 1 time. I tried to make a `bevegelse_2` with a delay, however, that also set a delay to the original `"bevegelse"`. The div `"fiende"` are my enemies, and `"bevegelse"` is the div for movement(side to side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css animations doesn't work like this. I understand you want after they go line below, the animation to be repeated from that position (moving them again down, and again).

Css animation is repeated from it's first frame, so to move them row by row to the bottom you need to define all the rows positions (with animation-fill-mode: forwards; added to the element, so it doesn't go up after animation is finished):

```
@keyframes bevegelse {
  0% {
    left: -230px;
    top: 0%;
  }
  10% {
    left: 250px;
    top: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 250px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  30% {
    left: -230px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  40% {
    left: -230px;
    top: 100px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 100px;
  }
  60% {
    left: -230px;
    top: 150px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 150px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  90% {
    left: 230px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 230px;
    top: 250px;
  }
}
```